# In an array, for all element , how to find out if there exists n-1 or n+1 for each in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have tried out with the following code

```
static int isBean(int...a){
    int isbean=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <a.length; j++) {
            if(a[i]+1!=a[j]||a[i]-1!=a[j]){ 
            isbean=0;
            }



        } System.out.println(" ");
    }

    return isbean;
}


   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr= {2, 10, 9,3};
    System.out.println(isBean(arr));
}
```

Result: 0
The result should be 1 as

```
 2  = 3-1,    
 10 = 9+1,  
 3  = 2 + 1,  
 9  = 10 -1
```

Where in my code did I do wrong?

Comment: *"Where in my code did I do wrong?"* You set `isbean=0` if *any* two values are not one apart. `2` and `10` are not one apart. `3` and `3` are not one aparts. Those are just two examples of values you compare, so `isbean` *will* be set to `0`.

Comment: (if you really care about your question, the link above point to a site with useful information about how to fix questions on [so], despite the weird name)

Comment: at least give your logic....

Comment: My *logic* says that your code is wrong. Oh, did you mean that I should write the code for you? Not going to happen.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to make all elements unique, sort them and check two neighbors of each element

Comment: Another potentially faster _O(n)_ solution would be to add all elements to a `HashSet`, then check if all values have a neighboring value in the `Set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your code just a bit:

```
static int isBean(int...a){
    int isbean=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

    boolean isFound = false;
        for (int j = 0; j <a.length; j++) {
            if(a[i]+1==a[j]||a[i]-1==a[j]){ 
            isFound = true;
            break;
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(" ");
        if(!isFound){
                isbean= 0;
                break;
            }
    }

    return isbean;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: @RamakantaBisipa, please accept and upvote if that helped. Thank You

Comment: You should add an explanation to the answer.

Comment: (also personally I think that give the OP the whole code is not the best way for them to learn. You get the +15, but does it worth it?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this solution should work in O(nlogn+n)

```
 int isBean=0;
    int a[] ={2, 10, 9,3};

    Arrays.sort(a);   
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]-1)
        {
            isBean=1;
        }

    }
```